# Why does the digit 1 appear most frequently in the first 15 million primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Wrote a program to loop thru all primes in the range $[2,275604541]$ and tallied the number of times each digit $0$ thru $9$ appeared for each prime.

For example, prime 15485863 has these values (**digit:frequency**)

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 0
3: 1
4: 1
5: 2
6: 1
7: 0
8: 2
9: 0
```

Here's a chart for the first 15 million primes showing the frequency of each digit:

[image: 15-million-primes]

**Question**

Is there an underlying law which shows why digit 1 seems most common?

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments, the tally for 2 to 99,999,999 gives this:

```
0: 324133
1: 570157
2: 400626
3: 564650
4: 397474
5: 396020
6: 395621
7: 560506
8: 394398
9: 558956
```

showing it still prefers 1 more slightly.

Comment: See [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law). ETA: Prime numbers aren't strictly speaking random, but they are (almost surely) distributed in such a way that a version of Benford's law applies.

Comment: Oh, you mean *all* digits. Well, there's obviously a bias for first and last, but beyond that I don't know.

Comment: Looking at the fact it's not significantly more that the frequency of the others it might just be a combination of benford's law and the fact there tend to be more odd numbers (except 5) in primes since they can't be even or a multiple of 5 (bar 2). This is just speculation though.

Comment: It’s not really benford’s law, though. It is because smaller numbers are more likely to be prime than larger numbers. So a number starting 1 is more likely to be prime than a number of the same length starting with 2. For later digit, it is more likely for a number starting 31 to be prime than a number starting 32. Each digit is just a little more likely. Last digits also exclude $2,4,5,6,8,0,$ so there is added skew there, but it doesn’t count as much.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yeah, it's not exactly Benford's law, you're right. But it does take advantage of the fact that its distribution is more tailed off than (say) a sequence in which each natural number is equally likely to be selected. It's a hint of Benford's. :-)

Comment: Of course, ending your program at a number starting with $2$ means the first digit is even more likely to be $1.$ The number of primes from $100,000,000$ to $199,999,999$ is  not much smaller than the number of primes from $2$ to $99,999,999.$ Try stopping the count at $99,999,999$ and you should get a more even number, but still preferring $1.$

Comment: Also, try counting the frequencies of the digits excluding the first and last. There might still be a higher probability for $1$ over the other digits, but it won’t be nearly as large. We probably get that the limit of  percentages  including all digits (first, last, and in between) is even. Might even be able to prove that via Dirichlet. Not sure.

Comment: I'm really surprised that $2$ appears as a digit more than $7$. Shouldn't Benford's Law be offset by the fact that there are many primes ending in a $7$, but there are none [well, one!] primes ending in a $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your tested integers (in particular, 100000000 up to 199999999) start with 1. The second most common leading digit is 2 (in particular, 200000000 up to 275604541). In the lower about one third (1 up to 99999999) all non-zero leading digits including 1 and 2 occur evenly. There are enough primes in the range considered and their density decreasing slowly enough to make this bias still visible for leading digits of primes in that range.

There is also a bias for final digits, namely 2 and 5 occur only once and otherwise 1,3,7,9 are evenly distributed (Dirichlet). For digits in intermediate places, it is safe to assume that all ten digits occur quite evenly (or perhaps with a smallish bias towards smaller digits, in fact slightly more zeroes than ones. Ultimately, the strong advantage of 1 in the leading and final digits prevails